# Custom Client Side Data Annotation using Dependent properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that calls partial view dynamically.

**Model Object Example:**

```
public class ParentModel
{
public int id {get; set;}
public List<ChildModel> childModel {get;set;}
}

    public class ChildModel
    {
   [NameRequired("eligibility","coupon","activeId")]
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string eligibility{get; set;}
    public string coupon {get; set;}
    public int activeId {get; set;}
    }
```

**View Example:**

ParentView.cshtml

--using parent model

```
@usng(Html.BeginForm())
{
-- additionalFields
<div id="addNewRow">
</div>
<input type="button" value "Add Row">
}
```

ChildView.cshtml

--using childModel

```
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem())
{
--additional fields
}
```

I add the childView as a partialview to addNewRow div dynamically using jquery on button click.

-- Additional code:

```
public class NameRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
 public NameRequiredAttribute (string eligibility,string coupon,string activeId)
            : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
         {
            this.eligibility = eligibility;
this.coupon = coupon;
activeId = activeId;

        }

 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
// server side validation code
}

public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {





            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
            {
                ValidationType = "namerequired",
                ErrorMessage = DefaultErrorMessage,
            };

            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("eligibility",BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext,this.eligibility));
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("coupon", BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext,this.coupon));
             rule.ValidationParameters.Add("activeid", BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext,this.activeId));


            yield return rule;

        }
        private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext,string propertyName)
         {
            // build the ID of the property
            string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(propertyName);
            // unfortunately this will have the name of the current field appended to the beginning,
             // because the TemplateInfo's context has had this fieldname appended to it. Instead, we
            // want to get the context as though it was one level higher (i.e. outside the current property,
            // which is the containing object (our Person), and hence the same level as the dependent property.
             var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
            if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
                // strip it off again
                depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
             return depProp;
        }
}

Jquery:

$.validator.addMethod(
     'namerequired',
     function (value, element, params) {
         var eligibility = params.eligibility;
         var coupon = params.coupon;
          var eligibility = params.eligibility;
         var isin = params.isin;
         var endingBal = params.endingbal;
         var copoun = params.copoun;
         var maturityDate = params.maturitydate;


         var dependentElement = $('#' + eligibility);

         var type = $(dependentElement).attr("type"),
             actualVal = $(dependentElement).val();
         alert(actualVal); // This is returning as undefined
      });

 $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
     'namequired', ['eligibility', 'coupon', 'eligibility', 'activeid'], function (options) {
         var params = {
              trancheName: options.params.eligibility,
             coupon: options.params.coupon,
             activeid: options.params.activeid,


         };
         options.rules['namerequired'] = params;
          options.messages['namerequired'] = options.message;
     });
```

**My question is as follows:**

I need to add a custom data annotation on client side to childModel "name" property using the below condition:

Enable required field for that specific name row only when data is entered in any one or all of the eligibility, coupon , activeId UI fields (This should repeat to all dynamically added rows)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You probably might need a conditional data annotation validation.. You may check this  [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: I tried this approach before. But I am getting dependentproperty value as undefined in jquery                                                                var id = '#' + parameters['dependentproperty'];                                                      var control = $(id);
         var controltype = control.attr('type');
         var actualvalue =
             controltype === 'checkbox' ?
              control.attr('checked').toString() :
              control.val();
  actualvalue  and controltype are resulting in undefined. Do we need to do any additional logic?

Comment: post your code please (that will help to figure out the issue). Are you passing the dependent property to your custom data annotation. Where are you setting the dependent property ?